# Formatting JSON in PHP from MySQL array for JQPlot

Tags: php, mysql, json, jqplot

I've looked at the other topics concerning passing JSON data to feed JQPlot but can't quite seem to find what I need. The issue is that I can't get the JSON data formatted correctly. (Yes, this is my first time with formatting and using JSON) I've tried all kinds of combinations, but I'm still looking for the right one.

JQPlot wants to see the data as

```
[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]]
```

but the best I've been able to output is

```
[x,y][x,y][x,y][x,y]
```

I'm hoping that someone might be able to tell me what I'm missing. My code is below...

```
$sql = "SELECT client_id, SUM(gross) FROM s_pr_wcomp GROUP BY client_id ORDER By SUM(gross) DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($mysql,$sql) or die(mysqli_error('Top 10 Query Failed!'));

// Encode Top 10

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
$grossTop = array(
    $grossTop[] = $row['client_id'],
    $grossTop[] = '$'.number_format($row['SUM(gross)'], 2)
);

header('ContentType: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($grossTop);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like your array should be imploded with a comma as glue and wrapped in a new array before it is encoded ?

Comment: Someone else had mentioned that in a post somewhere but didn't give an example. I tried reading up to wrap my head around it to no avail. Would it be possible for you to elaborate on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to append an array to the `$grossTop` array. Inside your while loop have something like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $grossTop[] = array(
        $row['client_id'],
        '$'.number_format($row['SUM(gross)'], 2)
    );
}
header('ContentType: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($grossTop);
```

Comment: That's looking a bit better but it is incrementally duplicating entries with each pass and encasing each one in an extra set of brackets... [[a,b]],[[a,b]],[[c,d]],[[a,b]],[[c,d]],[[e,f]]

Comment: Are you sure you are using the above code exactly? Because the output you are seeing is (most certainly) because of the way you are using `$grossTop` inside the loop:  `$grossTop=array($grossTop[]=$row['..'],$grossTop[]='$'.$row[..])` (WRONG!)

Comment: copied and pasted to make sure

Comment: I edited my answer, Check again. You were echo-ing the JSON inside your loop.

Comment: PERFECT! I knew it would be something stupid like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, wrap each iteration of $grossTop in another array.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
$grossTop = array(array(
    $grossTop[] = $row['client_id'],
    $grossTop[] = '$'.number_format($row['SUM(gross)'], 2))
);
```

Comment: I tried doing that one before, but then it wraps each entry in extra brackets rather than grouping them all in one set of brackets separated by commas... [[x,y]][[x,y]][[x,y]] Thanks for the input though! Every little bit helps.

Comment: OK. How about adding an extra set of square brackets to the $grossTop variable? `$grossTop[][] = $row[...`

Comment: ...or add a number iteration $i++; and do `$grossTop[$i][] = $row[...`